# CRT monitor refresh rate

Tags: ubuntu, monitors

I have Ubuntu14.04 64bit installed on computer with a CRT monitor. In Windows I could set the monitor's refresh rate to 85Hz. But Ubuntu's `xrandr` reports that maximum is 60Hz for 1024x756. Is there a way to fix this?

I installed current nvidia Ubuntu driver in repo; nothing changed.

**Edit1:**

```
$ xrandr --properties
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
SignalFormat: VGA
supported: VGA
ConnectorType: DVI-I
ConnectorNumber: 0
_ConnectorLocation: 0
VGA-0 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
SignalFormat: VGA
supported: VGA
ConnectorType: VGA
ConnectorNumber: 1
_ConnectorLocation: 2
1024x768 60.0*+
1360x768 60.0 59.8
1152x864 60.0
800x600 72.2 60.3 56.2
680x384 60.0 59.8
640x480 59.9
512x384 60.0
400x300 72.2
320x240 60.1
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
SignalFormat: TMDS
supported: TMDS
ConnectorType: DVI-I
ConnectorNumber: 0
_ConnectorLocation: 0
```

**Edit2:**

```
$ gtf 1024 756 85

  # 1024x756 @ 85.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.49 kHz; pclk: 92.87 MHz
  Modeline "1024x756_85.00"  92.87  1024 1088 1200 1376  756 757 760 794  -HSync +Vsync

$ xrandr --newmode "1024x756_85.00"  92.87  1024 1088 1200 1376  756 757 760 794  -HSync +Vsync
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)                                                                                           
  Serial number of failed request:  27                                                                                                         
  Current serial number in output stream:  27
```

**Edit3:**

```
$ xrandr --newmode  "myrate" 92.87  1024 1088 1200 1376  756 757 760 794  -HSync +Vsync
$ xrandr --addmode VGA-0 myrate
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  27
  Current serial number in output stream:  28
```

Comment: If you run `xrandr --properties`, does it report an EDID for your display?

Comment: I added the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that your monitor support the desired configuration, you can add a new mode for your screen.

First, ask `gtf` for a correctly formatted mode line :

```
> gtf 1024 756 85
# 1024x756 @ 85.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.49 kHz; pclk: 92.87 MHz
Modeline "1024x756_85.00"  92.87  1024 1088 1200 1376  756 757 760 794  -HSync +Vsync
```

Then create the new mode with the output of `gtf`.

```
xrandr --newmode "1024x756_85.00"  92.87  1024 1088 1200 1376  756 757 760 794  -HSync +Vsync
```

Add the mode to your output (which may be VGA-0, DVI-1, etc.):

```
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1024x756_85.00
```

And finally select the new mode:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1024x756_85.00
```

Source: [Ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1112186)

Comment: it has an error. see edit2

Comment: @user69453 HAve you tried several resolutions/modes? If it doesn't work, it's probably because the driver you use under Linux doesn't support the settings you want.

Comment: I don't know. btw, my question contains my last effort.

Comment: @user69453 No more ideas... :-/ I guess the problem is that your driver doesn't support the settings you want.

Comment: The same monitor has 85 Hz refrash rate with windows. It does not seem to be a graphics card problem. Probably there is a bad monitor driver!